# Ticks in dc don't align

Tags: dc.js

I am plotting bar charts using dc.js and this is the code that I use. However, my ticks don't come at the center of the bar.They come at the end.This is how my code looks like:

```
barChart5.width(600)
             .height(250)
             .margins({top: 10, right: 100, bottom: 20, left: 80})
             .dimension(pfmValue)                               
             .group(pfmValueGroupSum)
              .valueAccessor(function (p) {return p.value.avgIndex;})
             .transitionDuration(800)   
             .yAxisLabel($('metric').value)
             .gap(200)                                            
             .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["CORESITE", "MWEB"]))
             .brushOn(false)
             .title(function(d) { return d.key + ": " + d3.round(d.value.avgIndex,2); })
             .elasticY(true)
             .barPadding(0.5)
             .centerBar(true)
             .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);
```

How can I bring them to the center of the bars and also how do I make sure that the Y-axis labels don't overlap(here it doesn't, but in some other charts, it does).

Comment: For the text overlap problem, there is the [rotate text renderlet](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/TjXkTTbOhsQ). As for the ticks, I'd think that centerBar would do it. Could you share a jsFiddle?

Comment: fixed this issue by rotating text field..Do we have any example anywhere for grouped bar charts??Do reply back on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249707/can-this-be-done-in-dc-and-crossfilter